# Focus language grammar

Tags: antlr4, grammar, mainframe, cics, microfocus

I need to extract some info from a list of mainframe scripts written in [focus language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOCUS).
I'm trying to write a java program for parsing source code. Due to the name of the language it is difficult to find any useful information on the internet. Maybe someone know if exist a grammar for this language on internet(for example for antlr4) or maybe an implemented lexer.
Thanks in advance for any response!

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link to the [*Focus Developer Manuals*](https://ecl.informationbuilders.com/focus/index.jsp), then click on the left side to open the list of manuals available.

Note: The link to "FOCUS Developer Manuals" at the bottom of the the WikiPedia page was `http://...` instead of `https://...`, and resulted in a *connection refused* error. I have corrected the Wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a curated list of ANTLR grammars [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).  Unfortunately, there is no grammar for the focus product.

Not all authors make their grammars available at the above link, you might try searching github and other code repositories.